# Embed Google Fonts in Mailer

Tags: html, css, mailer

```
@font-face {}
font-family {}
```

Is it possible to embed Google fonts in mailer for all mail clients? If yes, how?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like No. Not for most mail clients (there are so many and so many versions of each). But you can for some - here is a good article about it:
https://www.campaignmonitor.com/blog/email-marketing/2012/12/using-web-fonts-in-email/